# How to randomly chose any number of elements from array while reading it

Tags: arrays, probability-theory

I need to randomly (with equal probability) pick some fixed number of elements from array which is in the file. I want to read file once and just keep picked elements because an array can be very long and I don't want to keep it in memory. There should be equal probability that each subarray is chosen. And also at the beginning I don't know the size of array.

How can I do it?

Comment: I have edited your question to add the additional very important requirement you mentioned in a comment. Hope you don't mind - this changes the problem significantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something called Reservoir Sampling.

It's explained pretty well in this blog:

http://gregable.com/2007/10/reservoir-sampling.html

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the exact number of elements you are picking up, an easy solution would be to read the file and pick each element with a fixed probability.

If you want an exact number, you would need to know before reading the whole file how many elements there are in this file, compute a list of elements you want (as a list of integers), then read the file and pick the right elements.

Comment: It's a very big array, so it would take a lot of time to read it twice. The main idea is to just read it once. Also I have an exect number of elements I need to chose